# Cannot find module 'hbs', Handlebars template engine

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine, hbs

I don't know why it gives this error. I have also set `view engine` to `hbs` using `app.set()`, also defined path of `views` (path is correct, no error there). But it still says cannot find module `hbs` (it is already installed) when I try to render.

You can see that I am using `get()` request to `render()` the `index.hbs` file inside `Views` folder. Why is it showing this error?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

....It's somewhat silly of me, but it was because of another `node_modules` outside the project directory `ExpressProject`. You can see that there is another `node_modules`(in the bottom) outside `ExpressProject`.
But what I don't get here now, is that why is the outer `node_module` affecting `ExpressProject`directory?

It has it's own `node_modules`, and I am also running the server from `ExpressProject` directory, not from outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm i --save express-handlebars`. that should do the trick.